# Cant fetch records that have null values in columns

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query fetches all the rows however even if one column of a particular record is null it will fetch all records except that record.
I want a  query to fetch all values irrespective of whether it has null values in the column or not.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM
    STUDENT S,COURSE C
 WHERE S.STD_ID like '%'||null||'%' 
    and S.STD_NAME like '%'||null ||'%' 
    and S.STD_START_DATE like '%'||null ||'%' 
    and S.STD_END_DATE like '%'||null ||'%' 
    and S.STD_GENDER like '%'||null||'%'
    and S.COURSE_ID like '%'||null||'%' 
    and S.COURSE_ID=C.COURSE_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think that you should change the where condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM
STUDENT S,COURSE C
WHERE
S.COURSE_ID=C.COURSE_ID
```

This select take all records with null or not null values in ani column except COURSE_ID.

Ok then you should use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
STUDENT S,COURSE C
WHERE (S.STD_ID like '%'||user_input||'%' or S.STD_ID is null)
and (S.STD_NAME like '%'||user_input ||'%' or S.STD_NAME is null) 
and (S.STD_START_DATE like '%'||user_input||'%' or S.STD_START_DATE is null) 
and (S.STD_END_DATE like '%'||user_input||'%' or S.STD_END_DATE is null) 
and (S.STD_GENDER like '%'||user_input||'%' or S.STD_GENDER is null)
and (S.COURSE_ID like '%'||user_input||'%' or S.COURSE_ID is null) 
and S.COURSE_ID=C.COURSE_ID
```

Comment: Actually the query executes based on user input thats why the values in the where need to be written

Comment: @user2218550, let me know if you resolved the problem ;)

Comment: user2218550 Great! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
      STUDENT S
      FULL OUTER JOIN COURSE C 
           ON S.COURSE_ID = C.COURSE_ID
```

this select take all records with null or not null values in any column.